# Вывод одной кнопки в таблицу

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать чтобы кнопка сформировать заказ-наряд выводилась только на одну первую строку, где указывается ID заказа клиента. То есть эта таблица формирует итоговый заказ наряд. ID Итогового заказа это первичный ключ, ID заказа клиента вторичны и услуга тоже вторичный. Т.к. в заказ-наряде может быть несколько услуг в одном заказе, поэтому при добавлении новой услуги нужно добавлять новую запись к тому же ID заказа клиента, только уже с другой услугой. Сейчас у меня кнопка выводится на все строки, но нужно как-то сделать чтобы она выводилась только на одну запись с ID заказа клиента, а на повторяющиеся с другими услугами не выводилась. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно организовать ? Структура таблицы с заказ-нарядами idserviceorder - PK, idorderclient-вторичный ключ из заказа клиента, idservice - вторичный ключ с названием и стоимостью услуги.
Прилагаю фото таблицы на всякий случай
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <?php
            
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `serviceorder`";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)
            {
                ?>

            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID итогового заказа</th>
                        <th>ID заказа клиента</th>
                        <th>Услуга</th>
                        <th>Сформировать заказ наряд</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))
                        {
                            $idorderclient = $row['idorderclient'];
                            $orderclient = "SELECT * FROM orderclient WHERE idorderclient='$idorderclient' ";
                            $orderclient_run = mysqli_query($connection, $orderclient);

                            $idservice = $row['idservice'];
                            $service = "SELECT * FROM service WHERE idservice='$idservice' ";
                            $service_run = mysqli_query($connection, $service);
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['idserviceorder'] ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <?php 
                                    foreach($orderclient_run as $orderclient_row)
                                    {
                                        echo $orderclient_row['idorderclient'];
                                    } 
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php 
                                    foreach($service_run as $service_row)
                                    {
                                        echo $service_row['service'];
                                    } 
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form action="code.php" method="POST">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="serviceorder_delete_id" value="<?php echo $row['idserviceorder'] ?>">
                                    <button type="submit" name="serviceorder_delete_btn" class="btn btn-info">Заказ-наряд</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php        
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Записи не найдены";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: что-то код и картинка не особо соответствует.

Comment: почему не соответствуют ? я сейчас нажал "выполнить код" выглядит так же, как у меня только у меня заполнение из бд идет, тут он не заполняет потому что некуда подключаться. А так все именно так и есть

Comment: ну вы пишите, что кнопка нужна только в первой строке, а дальше у повторяющихся значений первого столбца кнопки быт не должно. Данный код не формирует повторяющиеся строки. все дочерние значения выводятся внутри td

Comment: перед закрытием tbody у меня есть еще закрытие php кода, как раз-таки оно и отвечает, чтобы кнопка формировалась у каждой строки